# Ionic3 set default when generate new page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to know how to set default import in the .ts file when i use CLI to generate a new page.

Example: I want to add additional import for my shared function:

`import { SharedFunctions } from '../functions/sharedFunctions.ts'`

As well as set the default constructor like:

```
constructor(public sharedFunctions:SharedFunctions ){
//... other codes
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to create your own cli command or a vs extension

Comment: Either follow @Mehdi's advise or just write a class eg. `SharedFunctionsClass` that imports `sharedFunctions` and extend this class every time you're creating a new page, like `export NewPage extends SharedFunctionsClass`...